# Python socket server receive image

Tags: python, image, sockets

I am trying to receive an image from Android to PC using socket in Python. My server code is as follows:

```
import socket
address = ("10.0.0.12", 5000)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(address)
s.listen(1000)


client, addr = s.accept()
print 'got connected from', addr

filename = open('tst.jpg', 'wb')
while True:
    strng = client.recv(1024)
    if not strng:
        break
    filename.write(strng)
filename.close()
print 'received, yay!'

client.close()
```

And it returns me a tst.jpg which is the same size of that on my Android. But I cannot open the pic.

Here is my Android code:

```
Socket photoSocket = new Socket(ipString, port);
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(photoSocket.getOutputStream());
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(PhotoActivity.filePath);
int size = fis.available();

byte[] data = new byte[size];
fis.read(data);
dos.writeInt(size);
dos.write(data);

dos.flush();
dos.close();
fis.close();
photoSocket.close();
```

Comment: seems all right to me. how do you send?

Comment: `filename` is not what the name may suggest. It's a fileobject instead.

Comment: @Daniel  know but that's not the point. Actually it seems that my android code is not good to send the images. I'll post them and would you please have a look at it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so the android code is sending the size as int in front of the data, but the python code doesn't read it.

```
import socket
import struct
address = ("10.0.0.12", 5000)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(address)
s.listen(1000)


client, addr = s.accept()
print 'got connected from', addr

buf = ''
while len(buf)<4:
    buf += client.recv(4-len(buf))
size = struct.unpack('!i', buf)
print "receiving %s bytes" % size

with open('tst.jpg', 'wb') as img:
    while True:
        data = client.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        img.write(data)
print 'received, yay!'

client.close()
```