# Sending an image file from an Android phone to a PC through Python using sockets

Tags: java, python, android, image, sockets

I want to send an image from my android device to python through sockets, I've been successful in sending text from Android-Python. 
When I send the image I get the toast of the image being sent but on the receiving end the image is corrupted with a 0 KB size 
I appreciate any help, as I'm currently stuck here.

Here is my code

image.py

```
from socket import *

port = 8888
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', port))
s.listen(1) #listens to 1 connection
conn, addr = s.accept()
print("Connected by the ",addr)

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as file:
       file.write(data)


conn.close()
```

The Android side code is,

```
public void send(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
    }

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            try {
                final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri); 
                final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);

                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                byte[] array = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

                SendImageClient sendImageClient = new SendImageClient();
                sendImageClient.execute(array);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "no image selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


 public class SendImageClient extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... voids) {

            try {
                Socket socket= new Socket("192.168.0.106",8888);

                OutputStream out=socket.getOutputStream();
                DataOutputStream dataOutputStream=new DataOutputStream(out);
                dataOutputStream.writeInt(voids[0].length);
                dataOutputStream.write(voids[0],0,voids[0].length);
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                dataOutputStream.close();
                out.close();
                socket.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your python code is truncating the output file on every run of the loop. On the last run, when the connection is closed, the file is truncated, `conn.recv` will return an empty string, and nothing else will be written to the file.

Move `with open(..)` outside the loop that reads from the socket, and handle the connection closing so you don't have an infinite loop:

```
with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as file:
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data: break
        file.write(data)
```

Your java code is sending the size of the data it's sending before the data itself - you should either remove this or adjust the python code to take this into account.

```
            dataOutputStream.writeInt(voids[0].length);
            dataOutputStream.write(voids[0],0,voids[0].length);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I've tried as you said and now I am getting the image with the size of 3 KB but when I try to open the image it says file format not supported and for the android side I've tried the sending images android to another android device it works fine.

Comment: I've tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312468/python-socket-server-receive-image   solution as well, but I get error as "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str"

Comment: Are you still writing the length of the image data into the socket and into the file? That will make the file format unrecognizable to whatever you may use to open the file. Also, compare the exact size of the file in bytes, "more or less 3kb" is not good enough to detect problems

Comment: I am not mentioning any size in the code the size of the image data is calculating by voids[0].length

Comment: So you've removed this line of code? `dataOutputStream.writeInt(voids[0].length)`

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked when I remove this line :)